# vector<bool> arr Reset Issue

Tags: c++, vector, stl, boolean

For example,

```
vector<bool> arr(10);
arr[0]=true;
```

And then, I want to reset the vector.
So,

```
arr.clear();
```

I expect vector with all elements zero because False is zero.

```
printf("%d", arr[0]);
```

But, Result num > 0;

Even the value before clear is the same as the value after clear !

What happened?

```
   // Test Code
    vector<bool> arr(101);
    arr[1] = true;
    printf("Before Value : %d\n", arr[1]);
    arr.clear();
    printf("Result : %d\n", arr[1]);

    // Test Code




vector<bool> arr(101);
printf("asdf : %d\n", arr.size());

// Test Code
arr[1] = true;
printf("Before Value and size : %d, %d\n", arr[1], arr.size());
arr.clear();
printf("Result and size : %d, %d\n", arr[1], arr.size());

// Test Code
```

Comment: *"I expect vector with all elements zero because False is zero."* - Why do you expect that? There's documentation, you shouldn't guess what a piece of API does.

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear

Answer (score 2):

After you call `clear()` the size of the vector becomes 0 so accessing any element using subscript operator `arr[0]` causes *undefined behavior*. If you try to access first item using `at()` method then behavior will be well-defined and it will throw `::std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: That mean is that after clear(),Are not arr(100) initialized to 0, just arr?

Comment: `clear()` does not mean `zero initialize`, it's a method to remove all the items from container. A rather misleading method name I guess.

Comment: Oh... I got it... I'm so sorry.  
And I have another question.